# Set Grouped Product Pages to 1 Column layout

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, product, grouped-products

How do i set the grouped product pages to 1 column layout.

We want to leave the standard/simple products as they are which is 2 column left and just change grouped products to 1 column

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento defaulty `create an unique handler on basic of product type` on product details page.

**It Logic like ::**`PRODUCT_TYPE_TypeId`

So for group product it create handler `PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped`

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>  
       <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
 </PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
```

just add this code at `local.xml or catalog.xml` on your theme layout folder

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<!-- add this ...... -->
<PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>  
       <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
 </PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
<!-- add this ...... -->
</layout>
```